# Can I export my Urban Airship push device tokens?

Tags: push-notification, urbanairship.com, devicetoken

I'm evaluating Urban Airship as a push solution and I was wondering if it's possible to export my device tokens should I decide to stop using their service?

I've noticed they have an API endpoint to download device data (http://docs.urbanairship.com/reference/api/v3/device_information.html#device-token-list-api) but I was wondering if anyone actually went through the process of switching their push solution from UA to an internal solution (i.e. run my own push server and ping old users).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is an API call for it, but you could go to Audience->device tokens, and make a script to fetch all of them.

In the company I work, we decided on a different approach.

All communication with Urban Airships goes through our own backend, where we at the same time store the devicetokens sent from the device. That way we can shift to another way of sending push notifications without modifying our apps. It is of course a bit more time consuming to do the initial development. On the other hand, if you go for the solution you are currently considering, the switch to you own implementation (or another push provider) will properly require several migrations, or at least maintaining two different ways of sending push notification for a considerable time.

BTW:we have been using UA for almost 3 years, and have been very happy with their service.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this info! So ideally I'd have my own database of tokens and store them as soon as users opt in, right? I assume that it's impossible to fetch a device's push token for a specific app after the initial user opt-in? That's where UA's API would come in handy.

Comment: Right! 
Yes, you will only get the token after opt-in and, according to the apple doc, in some rare circumstances. (see http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:)